# Oauth2 is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Hi everyone I am totally new on Nodejs and this is my 1st project but I am getting error (Oauth2 is not a constructor)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrLf4KMs71E&ab_channel=RajKapadiaRajKapadia
I follow the step by step but still showing error
please help me out.

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const { Oauth2 }  = google.auth;

const oAuth2Client  = new Oauth2(
    'ProvideYourClientID',
    'ProvideYourSecretKey'
    );

    oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
        refresh_token: 'YourRefreshToken'
    })

    const calendar = google.calendar({version:'v3', auth: oAuth2Client})
    
    //create form and send to the backend
 
    const eventStartTime = new Date();
    eventStartTime.setDate(eventStartTime.getDay()+2)

    const eventEndTime = new Date();
    eventEndTime.setDate(eventEndTime.getDay()+2); 
    //event long for 
    eventEndTime.setMinutes(eventEndTime.getMinutes()+45);

    //set the event
    const event ={
        summary: 'Meet with one24 team',
        location:'Bokaro',
        description: 'Meeting with team to know the progress of the day',
        start:{
            dateTime:eventStartTime,
            timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'
        },
        end:{
            dateTime:eventEndTime,
            timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'
        },
        colorId: 1
    }
    calendar.freebusy.query({

        resource:{
            timeMin: eventStartTime,
            timeMax: eventEndTime,
            timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata',
            items:[{id:'primary'}],
        },
    },(err,res)=>{
        if(err) return console.error('Free busy query Error: ',err);

        const eventErr = res.data.calendars.primary.busy

        if(eventErr.length === 0 )
        return calendar.event.insert(
            {calendarId: 'primary', resource: event },
            err => {
                if(err) return console.error('Calendar Event Creation Error: ' ,err)
            }
        )
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try checking the official documentation first [Node.js quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs) once you have that working and understand how it works it should be pretty Strat forward to alter it for inserting events.

Tip number one make sure to change the scope for inserting

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Calendar API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listEvents);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the next 10 events on the user's primary calendar.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listEvents(auth) {
  const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});
  calendar.events.list({
    calendarId: 'primary',
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    maxResults: 10,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const events = res.data.items;
    if (events.length) {
      console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
      events.map((event, i) => {
        const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
        console.log(`${start} - ${event.summary}`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No upcoming events found.');
    }
  });
}
```